# Compiling libgdiplus-2.10.9  on Centos5 for Mono

Tags: compilation, mono

Fresh install of Centos5 32 & 64 on vmware vps...

```
yum install gcc glib2-devel bison libX11-devel freetype-devel fontconfig-devel gcc-c++ libpng-devel
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/libgdiplus/libgdiplus-2.10.9.tar.bz2
tar jxfv libgdiplus-2.10.9.tar.bz2 
cd libgdiplus-2.10.9
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono
make && make install
```

Here is the output:

```
[root@localhost libgdiplus-2.10.9]# make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9'
Making all in pixman
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9/pixman'
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9/pixman'
Making all in pixman
make[4]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9/pixman/pixman'
source='pixman-access.c' object='pixman-access.lo' libtool=yes \
        DEPDIR=.deps depmode=none /bin/sh ../depcomp \
        /bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -c -o pixman-access.lo pixman-access.c
../libtool: line 852: X--tag=CC: command not found
../libtool: line 885: libtool: ignoring unknown tag : command not found
../libtool: line 852: X--mode=compile: command not found
../libtool: line 1018: *** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.: command not found
../libtool: line 1019: *** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: Xgcc: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: X-DHAVE_CONFIG_H: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: X-I.: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: X-I..: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: X-g: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: X-O2: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: X-Wall: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: X-fvisibility=hidden: command not found
../libtool: line 1162: X-c: command not found
../libtool: line 1214: Xpixman-access.lo: command not found
../libtool: line 1219: libtool: compile: cannot determine name of library object from `': command not found
make[4]: *** [pixman-access.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9/pixman/pixman'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9/pixman'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9/pixman'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[root@localhost libgdiplus-2.10.9]#
```

Comment: I've given up in favor of CentOS 6, concluding that it does not work on CentOS 5.

Answer (score 33):

`export echo=echo`

From [this nabble](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Can-t-seem-to-compile-gdiplus-from-svn-td1549340.html):

> For some reason the libtool script being generated by autogen contains lines referring to "$echo message" instead of "echo message".
>
> exporting echo=echo worked, despite being totally wierd.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution:

```
[root@oscar libgdiplus-2.10.9]# pwd
/root/libgdi/libgdiplus-2.10.9

[root@oscar libgdiplus-2.10.9]# ls -la libtool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 292559 Jul  8 14:12 libtool

[root@oscar libgdiplus-2.10.9]# ls -la pixman/libtool
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 211592 Jul  8 14:12 pixman/libtool
```

You can see that the two files "libtool" are different:

```
mv pixman/libtool pixman/libtool.old
cp libtool pixman/libtool
```

It works!!!

Answer (score 3):

Try install autoconf >= 2.68 and use

```
yum install autoconf-2.68 gcc glib2-devel bison libX11-devel freetype-devel fontconfig-devel gcc-c++ libpng-devel 
wget http://download.mono-project.com/sources/libgdiplus/libgdiplus-2.10.9.tar.bz2
tar jxfv libgdiplus-2.10.9.tar.bz2 
cd libgdiplus-2.10.9
autoreconf -fiv
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono
make && make install
```

Answer (score 1):

I just compiled libgdiplus-2.10.9 on RHEL 4 !!! Used both fixes:

```
export echo=echo
```

and

```
mv pixman/libtool pixman/libtool.old
cp libtool pixman/libtool
```

Thanks guys for all this. You saved me some days:)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found a solution in a forum. Please try to run `autoconfig fi` from the shell in the source directory (for example '/usr/local/src/libgdiplus-2.10.9').
As far as i understand this is an issue with 'libtool', libgdiplus should compile after running this command.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded compiling libgdiplus-2.10.9 on CentOS 5 (x86-64) after installing required packages. It was essential to have autoconf, automake and libtool in order to update configure scripts.

```
yum install autoconf.noarch automake libtool.x86_64
yum install fontconfig-devel.x86_64 freetype-devel.x86_64 glib2-devel.x86_64
autoreconf -fiv
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/mono
make
make install
```